# Functions in functions

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I have three functions f(x,y) , g(t) , and h(t) and somehow I have to find (d/dt)f(g(t),h(t)) where t = 0. How would I go about writing this in Mathematica? In this equation g(t) is taking place of  x and h(t) is taking place of y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D[f[g[t]*h[t]], t] /. t -> 0
```

> Derivative[1][f][   g[0] h[0]] (h[0] Derivative[1][g][0] + g[0]
>   Derivative[1][h][0])

EDIT: I misread your post. Same approach

```
D[f[g[t], h[t]], t] /. t -> 0
```

> Derivative[1][h][0]*
>        Derivative[0, 1][f][g[0], 
>          h[0]] + Derivative[1][g][0]*
>        Derivative[1, 0][f][g[0], h[0]]